# what kind of HTML tag is this <gcse:search>?

Tags: javascript, html, tags

When I am try google custom search engine, I saw this   tag in code.
What kind of tag is this?
When and how to use this kind of tag and why?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Any tag of the form `<X:Y>` is a `Y` tag in the `X` namespace. In this case, the namespace is `gcse`, presumably "google custom search engine". Namespaces are useful when defining custom tags to help ensure they don't conflict with any others. Usually tags like this are manipulated by JavaScript, because the browser itself won't do anything special with them.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it is highly unrecommended, you can implement your own html elements.
A good example of this is the html5shiv which provides html5 elements to legacy browsers:

- nav
- main
- article

Now what Google are essentially doing the same, but with their own 'search' element.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link for details on `<gcse:search>`

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element